# Angular 7 can't get data from HttpGet in the .NET Core API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am migrating to the .NET Core API. For some reason, my GET API is working fine on Postman/a simple browser call, but I'm not able to reflect that result from my angular 7 service.

My API

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Employee>>> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        return await _service.GetAllEmployees();
    }
```

My Angular 7 service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Employee } from '../app/models/employee';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeesService {

  public employees: Employee[];

  constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) {
  }

  apiRoot: string = 'http://localhost:44301/api/employee';

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };

  public getAllEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {

    return this.httpService.get<Employee[]>(this.apiRoot, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
  );
  }

  private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
 
    let errorMessage = '';
    if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {

        errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
    } else {

        errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
    }
    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);
}
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular will not allow you to directly call APIs running on another port. For your case what you are looking for is to proxy your API calls to the server running on port 43301.

Create a file called proxy.conf.json next to you project’s package.json.

> {   "/api": {
>       "target": "http://localhost:44301",
>       "secure": false   } }

In your EmployeeService class change the apiRoot to simply "/api/employee"

Edit the package.json file:

> "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",

Relaunch the Angular project using "npm start"

Comment: Thanks for this sir, this works. I'm curious why the default controller from .net angular template works, while my custom not, perhaps the only change i made the "api" append on the URL.

Answer (score 0):

At first you can simplify your controller code.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllEmployees()
{
     return Ok(await _service.GetAllEmployees());
}
```

In this case there is no necessary to use HttpHeaders for GET request.

```
this.httpService.get<Employee[]>(this.apiRoot).pipe(...)
```

Have you imported `HttpClientModule` in your `app.module.ts`?

Also, your ASP.NET Core application have to allow CORS requests from another host.

In `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    // ...
    if (env.IsDevelopment() {
        app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Yes that would be good to enable CORS, I remember enabling this from older API versions